# How to stop Text Field from getting auto focused when accessing drawer in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, material-design, flutter-layout

> What is the problem

After entering something in my `textField`s in the lower blue part of the form and then accessing the drawer somehow focuses the last used `textField` and activates the keyboard.

[image]

> Expected Behaviour

When the drawer menu is triggered, the `TextField` should not get focused and keyboard should not come up.

**Side Note**
*Till I don't enter any data in the `textField` drawer action works correctly without activating the keyboard.*

> Code

**In the `main.dart` file:**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       //NavDrawer() is the custom Widget that renders the Drawer
      drawer: NavDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        ...<Normal Appbar Stuff>
      ),
        // BlogHome() is the custom Widget rendering the body
      body: BlogHome(),
    );
  }
}
```

**In the `BlogHome.dart` file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'form.dart';

class BlogHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
              new TextEditingController().clear();
            },
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...<Other Widgets>
              ],
            ),
          ),
           // This custom widget renders the blue colored form in the bottom
          FormData(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### `FormData.dart` file contains just two normal text fields and their styles in a stateful widget.

Comment: Use, FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
You can refer the below thread for it
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54277

Comment: @Kashifa you are absolutely correct mate thanks for help. Good Day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In the `BlogHome.dart` file**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'form.dart';

class BlogHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
// This line is unfocusing the current context that is calling unfocus upon itself
//But what it needs to do is call unfocus upon the primary focus
//So, commenting this line

              //FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

// This is the correct approach of calling unfocus on primary focus
  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
              new TextEditingController().clear();
            },
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ...<Other Widgets>
              ],
            ),
          ),
           // This custom widget renders the blue colored form in the bottom
          FormData(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### This is the correct solution `@Kashifa` you are absolutely correct.

[Follow this thread for more info.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54277)